# Printing IP version and IP Header in C

Tags: c, network-programming, ip, pcap

I have an assignment to write a packet sniffer in C. The sample code provided currently gets raw packets and parses link layer (Ethernet) header like so:

```
struct ethernet_header {
   unsigned char dest[6];
   unsigned char source[6];
   char proto;
}

...



 const struct ethernet_header *header;
   header = (const struct ethernet_header *)data_packet;

   printf("Source MAC: %02x", header->source[0]);
   for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) printf(":%02x", header->source[i]);
   printf("\n");

...
```

Now I need to parse internet layer.
For Internet Layer I have following struct:

```
struct ip_header {
        unsigned char  ip_vhl;          /* version << 4 | header length >> 2 */
        unsigned char  ip_tos;                 /* type of service */
        unsigned char  ip_len;                 /* total length */
...
};
```

Now ip_vhl is 8 bits long, and I want to get first 4 bits and printf it as a version and last 4 bits to printf it as a header length. Can you guys help me out here.

Also in sample code they used `%02x` to printf `header->source[i]` and `%hu` to printf `header->proto`. I would really appreciate if someone could explain it and what kind of `%..` I should use to printf ip_vhl, ip_tos and ip_len.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

- either use bitfields to describe 4-bit fields. Beware of implementation and platform dependent bit and byte ordering:

> ```
> struct foo {
>    int bar:4;
>    int baz:4;
> }
> ```

- or use logical operations to extract the bits.

> ```
> upper4bits = (bigvar >> 4) & 0xf; 
> lower4bits = bigvar & 0xf;
> ```

Comment: Thanks. This answers the forst part of the question, but what about the second?

Comment: Format strings just tell printf the type of variable to expect as the next parameter and how to show it. It's up to you to decide what you want to see. See http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf for format string details.